# How to recover the project accidentally deleted

Tags: xcode

I am very lost.

In My Finder, I search by all the files. and saw my Appname.xcodeproj

I lost every codes I have. How to I get back my Codes base on this project file?

please help.

--- Update

can any1 share a link on how to develop iOS swift app without StoryBoard.
Will this prevent accidentally delete?

Thanks

Comment: "You have lost" How ? have you deleted the project ?

Comment: Backup? Source control?

Comment: Restore it from your backup. If you have no backup, learn from this mistake the hard way.

Comment: At firstm My Main.StoryBoard is missing so I wen to waste bin to find it. I look for the Iproj folder. I copy and paste. then it show so many duplicate App folder. I just delete one and all swift file turn red. no source code reveal. Now, I have this xcodeproj  folder. What I need to do?

Comment: I dont have backUp!!!  I know it is my fault. is there any way to recover some files?

Comment: There is not. And not only you should have backups but you should absolutely use version control with Git.

Comment: I learnt my mistake. Sometimes, it just happened.

Comment: Start using Git now, don't wait. :) Take the habit of committing new code to the Git repository, and to upload it (push) to something like GitHub or BitBucket. This way if you delete your project or if your HDD is toast you will be able to download it and start working again (from the last commit, so, commit and push often!). Then with time you will learn other Git features like branches, etc.